# How can I block a Bot with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, bots

Im having problems with bot* and *bot.  I have limited knowledge of .htaccess but have been blocking bots with .htaccess rules below.

My question is in 2 parts:

1. Is my approach correct and if not how do I improve it, and
2. what is the correct syntaxt to block `*`bot and bot`*`

Many thanks in advance

```
#Enable RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On

# Stop the Nasties!!
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^autoemailspider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  baiduspider [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  baidu [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  Baiduspider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Baiduspider* [OR]

RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

Comment: thank you.  So how would I ban *bot and bot* who seem to be all over my site at the moment.

Comment: sorry my text didnt come out properly.  how do I ban asteriskbot and bot asterisk

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bot\ mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\ Demon [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus 
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

Yes, it is right way...

And, if you want to block any IP, then as an example:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all those conditions into one as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (autoemailspider|baidu) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

`NC` is for ignore case.